# Cruisecontrol.net and msbuild - how do I build multiple solutions under one project?

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

So, my application consists of 33 projects where more than half have interdependencies. I am using CruiseControl.net 1.6. I can build a single csproj or sln fine, but when I add more  tags, it bombs. How can I force build multiple csproj files?sdf

```
      <msbuild>
    <executable>c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
    <workingDirectory>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\MA_Release</workingDirectory>

    <projectFile>WorksFineWith1.sln</projectFile>
    <projectFile>ErrorsOutWithMoreThan1.sln</projectFile>

    <buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /p:Configuration=Debug</buildArgs>
    <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll</logger>
    <timeout>900</timeout>
  </msbuild>
```

How can I build multiples with one force build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use multiple `<msbuild>` tasks, you can have as many tasks in a `<project>` as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to allow MSBuild to handle this via Traversal projects.  There's a great MSDN article on building large source trees and using MSBuild Traversal here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483291.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are fine, but I'd prefer to have my CI build against a single solution file that is the exact same one that the developers use on a daily basis. This way, project/solution changes that would break the build are reflected in the developer's work environment.

If you have multiple separate solution files, then just set them up as different projects and use a `ProjectTrigger` to represent the dependencies.

[Project Trigger](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Project+Trigger)

Comment: Frankly I think that solution files become unwieldy in a large source control system and developer productivity goes up if they can just load the projects they care about to work. Divorcing the build system from solution files helps accomplish this.  Just my 2cents.  I've met people on both sides of the line on this one.

Comment: @Nick - I agree. A solution with more than 30-50 projects needs to be split up. A CI environment that has that many individual build steps is just as problematic and since I don't know his config, that's why I mentioned a single solution file, as well as multiple solution files with project triggers.

Comment: Currently, our dev team works on separate slns for each project (33 projects in all) 25 slns. I do agree with your philosophy of having one SLN for the entire application, it would make my life as a build manager easier, but it would make the dev team unhappy.

Comment: @MoreThanWYSIWG - As a build manager, you can do both, I've work at a place that does it where the bm has his own solution constructed and synchs it up when new projects are added. Although, that many solutions for so little projects sounds like quite a bit of dev pain to me, but I guess it depends on how the team is structured and the app is componentized.